# Cannot set value of input text form field

Tags: javascript, forms, input, tampermonkey

I have been trying to set the input values on a public DHL form in all the different ways the internet suggests, but it does not work.
I've tried the many Stack Overflow answers on this topic, but this form is just special.

[The DHL form](https://www.dhl.de/en/privatkunden/pakete-versenden/online-frankieren.html?type=ShipmentEditorAddressInput)

The classic way to set the value of the "first and last name" field:

```
// using firefox browser developer console:
var input = document.getElementById('address.receiver.name2');
input.value = 'John'; // has a temporary effect
// or
input.setAttribute('value', 'John'); // doesn't work
```

Setting `input.value = 'John';` shows the value inside the input field.
But any clicking inside and around the form or submitting the form, removes the value again.

Only the value that is manually typed in by hand, is preserved in the form.

I see that there is multiple events on the input field. I failed to either disable or trigger them. Also, the contents of the form are saved. Navigating and refreshing keeps the content. Seems to be a lot of magic going on.

I want to set the values of the input fields.

Comment: You have to fire a change event on that input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input

Comment: `But any clicking inside and around the form ...removes the value again`; sounds like there is another event firing on the form itself. You'll need to investigate that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? This worked for me [Solution for on change doesn't work when input is changed programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450386/solution-for-on-change-doesnt-work-when-input-is-changed-programmatically)

Comment: @Konrad Sadly, both top answers of your links did not work on the form I provided in my question.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: The default behavior of a form/input is not the way that you describe the issue. To open the question again you need to add details/code that makes the issue reproducible. You can see from all the comments that nobody have any clue what the issue is.

Comment: @chrwahl op doesn't have a problem with a default form, but a specific one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/how-can-i-enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field/57900849#57900849). – wOxxOm

This idea from wOxxOm worked.

Here is a **working solution** using `document.executeCommand` on the form:

```
// using firefox browser developer console:
var input = document.getElementById('address.receiver.name2'); // get the input field by id
input.focus(); // sets this input as the current one to manipulate
document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); // selects all content in the input field (so if there is something there already it gets overriden)
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'John'); // sets the field to string John
input.blur(); // removes focus
```